Azure Devops Pipline
I need your assistance in creating an Azure DevOps pipeline that prompts the user for input during runtime. I want to incorporate five stages, and for each stage, I want the pipeline to ask the user if they want to continue or not. Based on their input, the stage will either run or be skipped.
I've attempted to use parameters, but the issue I encountered is that all the choices appeared before the first stage, and nothing appeared before the other stages. Additionally, I tried creating a new environment and adding approval, but this is also not what I am looking for.
What I want is for the user to run the pipeline, then prompt a question to continue or skip. After their response, Stage 1 will execute based on the result. Then, another prompt will ask to continue or skip, followed by Stage 2 based on the user's choice, and so on
I have used this code:
parameters:
  - name: userChoice
    type: string
    default: 'Retry'
    values:
      - Retry
      - Skip

  - name: notifyChoice
    type: string
    default: 'Continue'
    values:
      - Continue
      - Skip

stages:
  - stage: UserChoiceStage
    jobs:
      - job: UserChoiceJob
        displayName: 'User Choice'
        steps:
          - script: echo "Please select an option Retry, Skip, or Continue"
            displayName: 'Prompt User Choice'
          - task: Bash@3
            inputs:
              targetType: 'inline'
              script: |
                echo "User Choice: ${{ parameters.userChoice }}"
            displayName: 'Display User Choice'

  - stage: Staging
    jobs:
      - job: StagingJob
        displayName: 'Staging Job'
        steps:
          - script: echo "Custom step execution"
            displayName: 'Custom Step (Retry)'
            condition: eq('${{ parameters.userChoice }}', 'Retry')

          - script: echo "Custom step skipped"
            displayName: 'Custom Step (Skipped)'
            condition: eq('${{ parameters.userChoice }}', 'Skip')

      - job: AnsibleJob
        displayName: 'Ansible Job'
        steps:
          - task: Ansible@0
            inputs:
              ansibleInterface: 'agentMachine'
              playbookPathOnAgentMachine: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/role/task.yml'
              inventoriesAgentMachine: 'noInventory'
              failOnStdErr: false
            displayName: 'Run Ansible Task'
            condition: eq('${{ parameters.userChoice }}', 'Continue')

  - stage: Notify
    displayName: 'Notify Eng and send email'
    dependsOn: Staging
    condition: succeeded('Staging')
    jobs:
      - deployment: NotifyJob
        environment: 'approve_stage'
        displayName: 'Notify Job'
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - script: echo "Please select an option Continue or Skip"
                  displayName: 'Prompt User Choice'

                - task: Bash@3
                  inputs:
                    targetType: 'inline'
                    script: |
                      echo "User Choice: ${{ parameters.notifyChoice }}"
                  displayName: 'Display User Choice'

      - job: NotifyAnsibleJob
        displayName: 'Notify Ansible Job'
        steps:
          - task: Ansible@0
            inputs:
              ansibleInterface: 'agentMachine'
              playbookPathOnAgentMachine: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)/role/notify.yml'
              inventoriesAgentMachine: 'noInventory'
              failOnStdErr: false
            displayName: 'Run Notify Ansible Task'
            condition: eq('${{ parameters.notifyChoice }}', 'Continue')

and the issue arises when I use parameters, as it makes 'userChoice' and 'notifyChoice' appear at the beginning.
Azure Pipline Parameters
For each stage, I want the pipeline to ask the user if they want to continue or not. Based on their input, the stage will either run or be skipped. Also, I tried to use the approval method, but this is not the way I am looking for. I want the steps for the pipeline to be as follows: 1. Give the user the choice of two options. 2. Based on the choice, the stage will be run. 3. Another prompt will appear to the user to choose from the other two options. 4. Based on the selected option, stage 2 will run... and so on.

make your question title reflective, as it is right now it is not clear. and you can perhaps change pipline to pipeline.

i have added more clarification, thanks

Your demand basically is possible not supported.
As a workaround, you can try the following method:
In each stage, you can add a Server job (Agentless job) as the very first job. In the Server job, you can add a ManualValidation task to pause the current pipeline run to wait for manual interaction.

Add the Server job: validation
Set the subsequent jobs to depend on the Server job.

stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: validation
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      displayName: 'Whether Continue'
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: '{emails of the users to notify}'
        instructions: 'Please confirm whether to continue running the subsequent jobs in this stage.'
  
  - job: A1
    dependsOn: validation
    . . .

  - job: A2
    dependsOn: validation
    . . .

- stage: B
  jobs:
  - job: validation
    pool: server
    steps:
    - task: ManualValidation@0
      displayName: 'Whether Continue'
      inputs:
        notifyUsers: '{emails of the users to notify}'
        instructions: 'Please confirm whether to continue running the subsequent jobs in this stage.'
  
  - job: B1
    dependsOn: validation
    . . .

  - job: B2
    dependsOn: validation
    . . .

NOTE: The ManualValidation task is available for YAML pipelines and classic build pipelines. If your pipeline is classic release, you can use the ManualIntervention task.

EDIT:
When a pipeline is running, users cannot update the values of parameters as parameters are expanded at compile time. The values of parameters should be specified in the YAML files before triggering or when manually triggering the pipeline.
So, the following steps you set in your pipeline do not work.
steps:
- script: echo "Please select an option Continue or Skip"
  displayName: 'Prompt User Choice'

- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      echo "User Choice: ${{ parameters.notifyChoice }}"
  displayName: 'Display User Choice'

As the workarounds, you can consider the following ways:

In YAML pipelines, you can set Approvals & Checks on each environments, however, this only available for deploy type jobs that target to the environments. If a stage does not contain deploy jobs, the checks on environments are not available. Before the stages which contain the deploy job starts, it will evaluate the Pre-approvals & Pre-checks set on the target environments. See "Create and target an environment" and "Define approvals and checks".

In classic build pipelines, you can only use the ManualValidation task in Agentless job like as suggested above. However, this is evaluated after the pipeline and Agentless job have started.

In classic release pipelines, you can set Approvals & Checks on Pre-deployment of each stage. Before the stage starts, it will evaluate the Approvals & Checks set on Pre-deployment. See "Release gates and approvals overview".




Thanks for your reply. I've included the code I've been using, but it's not meeting my expectations. I want the pipeline to prompt the user to choose from one of two options before running the stage

@Ranya, I have updated my above answer with more information (see EDIT).
